# Trying to fix flash from the 70's/80's AGFATRONIC 200B

Tags: repair, hotshoe-flash, vintage

The flash doesn't recharge so I'm trying to open the device but I lack the tools.
Can anyone identify the tool needed to open the device?

[image: Tool]

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a specialized spanner meant for the task, but a stick with a couple of brads (small finishing nails whose heads will fit in the holes) in it will do the trick in a pinch.

Comment: ...or bend a paperclip to shape. Also, obligatory caution about old capacitors: http://strobist.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-keep-your-old-flash-from.html